# How to set default value and value in react js Text Field at same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I have react Text Field with defaultValue.In defaultValue, I set the value using props. But I need to set onchage() event to that text field, So then I can update my TextField value.
But I can't set them. When I trying to set a value, my default value not showing.

```
          const [openingHours, setOpeningHours] = useState({
               monday: '',
           });


        const mondayHandler = (event) => {
                  const temp = {...openingHours};
                   temp.monday = event.target.value;
                 setOpeningHours(temp);
             };

         <TextField
                type="time"
                defaultValue={props.times[0].time1 !== undefined ? props.times[0].time1 : '00:00'}
                className={classes.textField}
                InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                    color: 'blue',
                }}
                InputProps={{
                    classes: {
                        underline: classes.underline,
                        root: classes.timeRoot,
                    },
                }}
            />
```

How to set Onchange event in to this text field..?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I am guessing that you are using `material-ui`'s TextField component. If I am wrong, this answer might not hold water.

By using value and onChange to control the state of the TextField you are creating what some people call a "controlled input". The `defaultValue` prop is meant to be used with uncontrolled inputs, not controlled. Instead, you can set a default value by supplying the correct initial value to `useState`.

What I'm suggesting would look something like:

```
        const [openingHours, setOpeningHours] = useState({
            monday: '00:00',
        });


        const mondayHandler = (event) => {
            const temp = {...openingHours};
            temp.monday = event.target.value;
            setOpeningHours(temp);
        };

         <TextField
             type="time"
             value={openingHours.monday}
             onChange={mondayHandler}
             ...
         />
```

You will have to verify that `00:00` is a valid value for a `TextField` with `type="time"`. You might need to supply a Javascript date object instead.